# How to stay on same page and render different component in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, uinavigationbar

I have navigation bar on my home page and i want to render my customers details after clicking on link on navigation bar on the same home page without going to different page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest react-router but if you want it like this it can be done in this way:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
<div onClick={()=>setPage(1)}> Page 1 </div>
<div onClick={()=>setPage(2)}> Page 2</div>

{
  page===1 && <h1>page 1 componenet here</h1>
}
{
  page===2 && <h1>page 2 componenet here</h1>
}
```

**Since you using react-router*(you said in comment)**
Home and About are your commponents (you can name whatever you want)

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route,NavLink, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
<BrowserRouter>
    <NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>

    <Switch>
        <Route path="/home"  component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: i am using react router please suggest me solution relevant to react router

Comment: sorry i did update them :)   but you can write anything in there based on your page

Comment: still after clicking on about it is going on different page i want to render it on same page like my navigation bar is on up side and customers details below that not on different page

Comment: the navlink part should be implemented at your navigation bar ,post your code in here https://codesandbox.io/s/new and i will fix it

Comment: sorry but i am unable to do that can u tell me right here only

Comment: post some part of your code in there if you need help, I already gave my help    see it carefully       the navlink needs to be implemented inside your NAVBAR (where you have    `<a>`  it needs to be `<Navlink>`)

Comment: Feel free to mark it as accepted answer, no one is gonna give more implementation than i already gave :)    have a nice day